# How to create the Cache for JPA Query in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, caching, spring-data-jpa

I have a table called Employee from this table I have a JPA Query to fetch the results

```
public List<Employee> findByDepartmentAngActiveFlag(@param("department") String department,@param("activeFlag") String activeFlag);
```

I want to create a cache for this method. For each department it has to fetch the records from DB and keep it in Cache ( I have update and fetch api department wise independantly). Same department wise I need to update the cache if any update happens on that department records.I have used this @Cacheable already but I couldn't able to use it by department wise.

Any suggestion would be helpfule to achive this.

Comment: Use hibernate 2nd level caching (check the documentation) which will integrate with your JPA provider. If you don't and use Spring Caching you will have to figure out when to remove stuff from the cache etc. yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using SpringBoot CacheManager and use Hazelcast inMemory cache.

[Oficial documentation](https://hazelcast.com/blog/spring-boot/)

```
// getting data
@Cacheable("Employee")
public List<Employee> getEmployees(String department, String activeFlag) 
{
    // Get logic goes here
}
```

When you will save employee Hazelcast will save it in local cache also and when you fetch it will first check in cache.

And you can call this method in your API function. Also make sure to use this class as Bean.